# Block or restrict Developers to create a branch in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-branch

How to block or restrict Developers to create a branch in GitHub?

It should always done by Admin or Administrator of the organisation

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (yet).

---

The closest thing to this is limiting who can push to/delete a branch.

Check that out here [enabling branch restrictions](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/).